# What is the value of the following contour integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> a)  Let C be the positively oriented simple closed contour consisting of the four
>   sides of the rectangle with vertices at $2, 3, 3 + 4i $ and $2 + 4i$. Is it true that $$|\begin{equation}
> \int_{C} \frac{ (\bar z^3 -10) e^{iz}}{Log  z} dz
> \end{equation}| < 2000 ?$$ 
>   b) Let $γ$ be the positively oriented rectangle with vertices at $−2 + i, 2 + i,
> 2 + 4i, −2 + 4i$. Is it true that \begin{equation}
> \int_{γ} \frac{ z- Log z}{z+Log  z} dz =0
> \end{equation}

This is what i have done so far:$$\\$$
a) Using the ML inequality $$|\begin{equation}
\ \frac{ (\bar z^3 -10) e^{iz}}{Log  z}
\end{equation}| \le \frac{(|z^3| -|10|) |e^{iz}|}{ln |z|} \le \frac{(5^3 -10)(e^{-4})}{ln 5} = M $$ $$\\$$ With $ \\ ln|z| \le ln |3+4i| = ln \sqrt 25 = ln 5 \,\ , |e^{iz}|= |e^{i(3+4i)}| =e^{x} = e^{-4} ,\ L = 10$  $$|\begin{equation}
\ \frac{ (\bar z^3 -10) e^{iz}}{Log  z}
\end{equation}| \le M L = 13.071.. < 2000 $$ $$\\$$

b)$Re (Log z) = ln|z| \le |2+4i| = ln \sqrt20 > -2 \ge Re (z)$ $ Since \ z+Log Z \ne 0 \ \text{and Log is not analytic only on }  (-∞,0]$\ by Cauchy Goursat Thm \begin{equation}
\int_{γ} \frac{ z- Log z}{z+Log  z} dz \ne 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Why would we care $\;\log z\;$ isn't analytic in a region that isn't even close to the given rectangle and its interior? Besides that, this is not a reason for the integral to be zero. We have $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^n}=0\;,\;\;\forall\,1\neq z\in\Bbb Z$$ and $\;\frac1{z^n}\;$ isn't analytic in $\;|z|\le1\;$ for $\;n\neq 0\;$

Comment: **non-zero** in the second line above.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok. But is the first part ok?

Comment: I don't like that much inequalities, but your first one is odd and probably wrong, since $\;|a|-|b|\le|a\pm b|\le|a|+|b|\;$ , and your numerators there are the other way around. Also how you estimmate the denominator isn't clear to me.

Comment: okay i'll work on it again